# Accessing System.Collections.Immutable and FrozenDictionary through reflection results in a type error

Tags: c#, .net

I want to include System.Collections.Immutable as an optional dependency for something I'm working on, and to do that I'm using reflection. Specifically, I want to be able to default to using a normal ReadOnlyCollection, but if System.Collections.Immutable is available then use a FrozenDictionary (as both can be casted to IReadOnlyDictionary).

```cs
Assembly assembly = Dependencies.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetName().Name == "System.Collections.Immutable");
Type staticFrozen = assembly.GetExportedTypes().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "FrozenDictionary" && x.IsAbstract && x.IsSealed);
MethodInfo method = staticFrozen.GetMethods().First(x => x.GetParameters().Length == 2);
IReadOnlyDictionary<char, float> dict = (IReadOnlyDictionary<char, float>)method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(char), typeof(float)).Invoke(null, new[] { baseDictionary, null } );
```

All of this is in a try catch block, for reference. The assembly itself is loaded through `Assembly.Load(byte[]);`, and loading it is successful.

But this gets this error when invoking the method (ToFrozenDictionary, the first method)

System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not find method '.ctor' due to a type load error: VTable setup of type System.Collections.Frozen.EmptyFrozenDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] failed assembly:data-000002C6933245E0 type:EmptyFrozenDictionary`2 member:(null)

I'm not entirely sure what to do (is there embedded resources or other dependencies that coudl cause this to break?) - I'm open to any ideas that would let me access System.Collections.Immutable without a hardcoded dependency that wouldn't break if it wasn't installed

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure your `GetMethods()` call actually yields `ToFrozenDictionary`? You're grabbing the first method containing 2 parameters, which could be anything.

Comment: @NPras yeah, there's only one method in the FrozenDictionary class with 2 parameters

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Searching for VTable setup errors seem to indicate that it's usually a DLL mismatch between the build version and the loaded assembly.

Comment: now that I think about that's probably the case, I couldn't find a dll targeting net48 so I used one that was a much higher version